# Why querySelectorAll is not working on my forms?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, fetch-api, selectors-api

I am very new to javascript. I was working on a Django project. In the project, multiple forms are created by Django. I used event listener to all of the forms. Here is my javascript code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    
    document.querySelectorAll(`#likeform${posts_id}`).forEach(e =>{
        e.addEventListener('submit',(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            like_function();
            // return false;
        });
    });
    
})



function like_function(){
    fetch(`/like/${posts_id}`,{
        method:"POST",
        body : JSON.stringify({
            "is_like" : is_like,
            "num_like" : num_like,
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        if(result.is_like){
            console.log("function is liked");
            console.log(`${result.is_like} for post ${posts_id}`);
            let num_like = result.num_like;
            console.log(`Number of posts : ${num_like}`);
            document.querySelector(`#likebtn${posts_id}`).innerHTML = "Unlike";
            num_like = num_like + 1;
            console.log(`Number of posts : ${num_like}`);
            document.querySelector(`#num_of_likes_${posts_id}`).innerHTML = `${num_like} `
            // location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000")
        }
        else{
            console.log("function is unliked, back off!");
            console.log(`${result.is_like} for post ${posts_id}`);
            let num_like = result.num_like;
            console.log(`Number of posts : ${num_like}`);
            document.querySelector(`#likebtn${posts_id}`).innerHTML = "Like";
            num_like = num_like - 1;
            console.log(`Number of posts : ${num_like}`);
            document.querySelector(`#num_of_likes_${posts_id}`).innerHTML = `${num_like} `
            // location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000")
        }
    })
    
}
```

I used querySelectorAll so that all forms work nicely. Unfortunately, only one form works. What goes wrong here?

As everyone is asking where I've defined `posts_id` in the comments, I'm editing my question and sharing my templates.html file.

> templates.html

```html
{% load static %}
<div id="likeapost{{posts.id}}" class="card-footer">
    {% if request.user in posts.likepost.all %}
        <form action="{% url 'likepost' posts_id=posts.id %}" id="likeform{{posts.id}}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
            <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
            <button id="likebtn{{posts.id}}" class="btn btn-link" type="submit">Unlike</button>
        </form>
    {% else %} 
        <form action="{% url 'likepost' posts_id=posts.id %}" id="likeform{{posts.id}}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
            <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
            <button id="likebtn{{posts.id}}" class="btn btn-link" type="submit">Like</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
    <small id="num_of_likes_{{posts.id}}" class="num_of_likes">{{ posts.likepost.all.count }}</small>
    
    {% block script %} 
        <script>
            posts_id = "{{ posts.id }}";
            is_like = "{{is_like}}";
            num_like = "{{ posts.likepost.all.count }}";
        </script>
        <script src="{% static 'network/controller.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    <button class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">Comment</button>
    <a href="{% url 'postpage' id=posts.id %}" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">View Post</a>
    {% if request.user.id is posts.user.id %}
        <a href="{% url 'editpost' id=posts.id %}" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">Edit</a>
       
    {% endif %}
    <!-- <div class="likepost"></div> -->
</div>
```

If I need to share more pieces of code please tell me.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(\`#likeform${posts_id}\`)` is targeting one form.

Comment: what is `posts_id`

Comment: You can not have several items with same `id`. May be you want use class selector instead of id selector

Comment: `#likeform${posts_id}` equals to `#likeformundefined` , since you never defined `post_id`

Comment: @Bravo I have multiple posts in my project. Each post has a unique id. I assigned them as posts_id.

Comment: It's searching #likeform for undefined.  At least per the code above.  What is defining posts_id?

Comment: @rakin235 where did you define `posts_id` ?

Comment: I've edited my question. I defined posts_id in HTML template.

Comment: The core issue your template has is that the values you define like `posts_id = "{{ posts.id }}"` will only hold the last value assigned and not a list. I would add a `data-posts-id="{{posts.id}}"` to the `form` in your template and select on that using `document.querySelectorAll("[data-posts-id]")`. Also pass that value to `like_function(this.getAttribute("data-posts-id"))`.

Comment: I solved it. but instead of like_function(this.getAttribute("data-posts-id")), I wrote like_function(e.getAttribute("data-posts-id")). If I would use this it would display getAttribute is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the elements with an id that starts with something, use the following :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="likeform"]').forEach((e=>{ // ...
```

Comment: You do not need the `#` while comparing as attribute.